# How do I prevent Views from sticking out of the rounded corner of a CardView?

Tags: android

Here's the XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" 
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp" 
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    app:cardElevation="2dp" app:cardCornerRadius="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

         <TextView
              android:text="TextView"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:id="@+id/textView10"
              android:layout_weight="2"/>

         <TextView
              android:text="Bids"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/textView11"
              android:layout_weight="1" 
              android:background="#ea6464"
              android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
              android:textAllCaps="true"
              android:textStyle="bold" 
              android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
     </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And here's what it ends up looking like:

[image: not rounded :(]

How do I tuck the `TextView` / `LinearLayout` under the corner so it doesn't stick out?

Comment: What you can do is create a drawable with rounded corners at the bottom and set that as the background of your `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I said in the comments section.

You can create a drawable with rounded corners at the bottom, then set that as the background.

Here is the shape I called it **rounded.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#e56067"/>

    <padding android:left="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"
        />

    <corners android:radius="1dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="16dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="16dp"/>

</shape>
```

Then change your layout to this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded.xml"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Bids"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The result will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have to create drawable with the bottom rounded corner like below and set it in `TextView` background property:

**shape_bottom_rounded_corner_red.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="#ea6464" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="16dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="16dp" />
</shape>
```

Set `android:background="@drawable/shape_bottom_rounded_corner_red"` in your `TextView`:

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_bottom_rounded_corner_red"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Bids"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

**Note: You have to set the same dimensions for `bottomLeftRadius` and `bottomRightRadius` in the drawable file which you have set in `cardCornerRadius` in `CardView`.**